# UITests fail when run with Fastlane

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5, fastlane, uitest

I am working on an `iOS` app and the goal is to successfully run tests using `Fastlane`.

When I run tests with `Xcode`, everything works fine. Tests are only failing when run using `Fastlane`.

This is the error message:

```
Failed to get matching snapshots: Lost connection to the application (pid 36570)
```

Which I think is not accurate because I don't have any snapshot call in my tests. I have also removed Snapshot plugin but still the same error message appears.

Does anybody have an idea what I can do?

Comment: Snapshot and screenshot are completely different

Comment: How do you run those tests? I had the same error message and the problem was that I prebuild the app with scan for iPhone and used this to generate screenshots with an iPad (which worked fine earlier, at least till the beginning of 2020)